# Error : cannot find D:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86/lib: Permission denied : Qt5

Tags: windows, gstreamer, qt5.2

I am developing my Application in Qt 5.2.1.

In **.pro** file:

`LIBS += "D:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86/lib"`

While build the project got the Error:

`error: cannot find D://gstreamer-sdk//0.10//x86//lib: Permission denied
error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I have tried `Run as administrator` to `Qt Creator` and also gives full permission to `gstreamer-sdk` directory recursively. But still facing the same issue.

I have also google it, but can not find any solution.

Guide me in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIBS` is a list of libraries, and you are adding a directory instead. You need to specify the name of the library, e.g.:

```
LIBS += "D:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86/lib/gstreamer-0.10.lib"
```

Check the qmake manual for more information: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

Also, I figured this might be helpful; here's an example .pro file that comes with QtGstreamer: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/qt-gstreamer/tree/examples/player/player.pro

The key bits seem to be:

```
QT        += widgets
CONFIG    += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += Qt5GStreamer-0.10 Qt5GStreamerUi-0.10
DEFINES   += QT_NO_KEYWORDS
```

Comment: Many Many thanks #Mark Tolley. Its really help me a lot. You deserved +1